# Oracle error: VLD 0350

Tags: oracle, warehouse

I am trying to deploy a dimension in Oracle Warehouse Builder, and when I do, I get error message

VLD-0350: In a hierarchy PARENT_LEVEL, level relationship binding
between parent level PARENT_LEVEL and child level CHILD_LEVEL does not
exist. Within a hierarchy a level relationship between levels must be
created using the surrogate key column of the parent.

I googled it, but I can't seem to find any answers on how to solve this.
Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-binding sometimes gets out of sync. Bind it again by following these steps:

- Project Navigator
- Select the dimension
- Right click on it  - 'Bind' to sync it again

Reference: https://gerardnico.com/wiki/dit/owb/dimension#vld-0350